# Retrieve an SMS in the service class

Tags: android

Here is the code I use to retrieve sms entering incoming sms!:

```
//---get the SMS message passed in---
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";
String strd = "";
String strm = "";
if (bundle != null)
{
//---retrieve the SMS message received---
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
 msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
//if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("9819861968")) {

    //---get the sender address/phone number---
    str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
   str +=":\n";
    strd += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    strd +=":\n";
  //  }
    //---get the message body---

str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
strm += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
```

// this.abortBroadcast();

```
    }
```

Now i would like to get the sms out and the number.
  please help me

Answer (score 0):

> I recover the sms well but not the default application of sms!

Remove `this.abortBroadcast();`, this will stop sending notification to another receiver which is waiting for this intent.

[Official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast())

> I can not make a pass of parameters to the class Service!

You can pass parameters from Broadcast to a service though intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, [Your service].class);
intent.put() // here you can add all the parameter
context.startService(intent);
```

and in your server `onStartCommand` you will get the intent data.

Comment: Okay. I'm testing

Comment: I am a beginner you can give me the instructions to send a parameter from the BroadcastReceiver class to the service class because remove this.abortBroadcast (); Did not give
And also the fact that the service runs before the BroadcastReceiver is not a problem? Case I even try to keep the sms in a SharedPreferences from the BroadcastReceiver and retrieve in the Service class but it first runs the Service
Please help me I'm dismissed for a week

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: thank you. Removing: this.abortBroadcast (); has worked.

Comment: You are Welcome :)